# Issue on Toggling Two Classes on Bootstrap 3 Radio Button Group

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to Toggle two classes `.btn-primary` and `.btn-default` ONLY on parent of the checked Radio on Bootsrap 3 radio Buttons at <kbd>[This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/cMALS/)</kbd>.  But as you can see from the example it only works at first check radio and incase of checking another radio the previous button loses both classes

```
$(function () {
    $('input:radio[name="opts"]').change(function () {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("btn-primary btn-default");
    });
});
```

can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick -

```
$(function () {
    $('input:radio[name="opts"]').change(function () {
        $('.btn').removeClass('btn-default');
        $('.btn').addClass('btn-primary');        
        $(this).parent().removeClass('btn-primary');
        $(this).parent().addClass('btn-default');
    });
});
```

Here is your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cMALS/1/